# how to use parent.parent.document.getElementById on firefox?? asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox, frame, getelementbyid

i have a javascript function that does work on Internet Explorer... but doesn't work on firefox nor google chrome.

Here's the example...

```
function CerrarFrame(src, id, tamArreglo)
{
    parent.parent.document.getElementById("workSheet").src = src;
}
```

now the asp form

```
<frameset rows="41, *" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" name="frmMain" id="frmMain">
    <frame name="topForm" src="Header.aspx" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" noresize>

    <frameset cols="168,*" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" id="frmBody">
        <frame name="frmMenu" id="frmMenu" src="MenuFrameNew.aspx?idUser=<%Response.Write(Session["idUser"]);%>&administrator=<%Response.Write(Session["administrator"]);%>&idCorp=<%Response.Write(Session["idCorporative"]);%>&file=<%Response.Write(Session["fileLogo"]);%>" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" noresize>

        <frameset id="frmContent" name="frmContent" rows="*,21" frameborder="0" framespacing="0">
            <frame name="workSheet" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="Body.aspx" scrolling="auto">
            <frame name="btm" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="footer.htm" scrolling="no">
        </frameset>
    </frameset>
</frameset>
```

This javascript works properly on IE, but when I use it on FireFox, I get this error:

```
TypeError: parent.parent.document.getElementById("workSheet") is null
```

Is there a way to work this around?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to change the `src` attribute of the frame `workSheet`. However, that frame doesn't have an `id` but just a `name`. That's why it fails in all browsers but IE: IE – at least some version of IE – doesn't make any difference between `name` attribute and `id` attribute, that's why it returns the object. You can either add an `id` to the frame (as you have done with `frmContent`) or using `frames` collection, like:

```
parent.parent.frames["workSheet"].src = src;
```

That uses the `name`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.frames.

Hope it helps.